# Redirecting after deleting an item is always returning null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC to build an application for Forums. I have an entity named `Posts` and an entity named `PostReplies`.

On a particular `Post`, there will be a list of replies which are linked by a FK `Post_Id` in my `PostReplies` entity.

When I delete a reply on a post and call:

```
RedirectToAction(GetPost, Post, new { id = post.id});
```

(gets the individual post, with list of replies on it)

I get an error relating to this bit of code:

```
var replies = post.Replies;
```

(the  post, always returns null)

I'm not sure why this is, it always redirects fine when I add a reply and then redirect back to the post.

I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong when I'm calling delete method. I'll expand the logic I have below:

`Post` entity:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual Discussion Discussion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostReply> Replies { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

`PostReply` entity:

```
public class PostReply
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

`ReplyController` - delete a reply:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteReply(int id)
{
    return View(_replyService.GetReply(id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteReply(int id, PostReply reply, Post posts)
{
    var replies = _replyService.GetReply(id);
    _replyService.DeleteReply(id, reply, posts);
    return RedirectToAction("GetPost", "Post", new { id = posts.Id });
}
```

`_replyService` logic (called in the controller above):

```
public void DeleteReply(int id, PostReply reply, Post posts)
{
    var replytoDelete = _context.Replies
                                .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);

    if (replytoDelete != null)
    {
        _context.Replies.Remove(replytoDelete);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`PostController` - get individual post:

```
public ActionResult GetPost(int id)
{
    Post post = _postService.GetPost(id);

    var replies = post.Replies;

    var listofReplies = replies.Select(reply => new NewPostReplyModel
            {
                Id = reply.Id,
                ReplyPosted = reply.Created,
                ReplyContent = reply.Content,
                ReplyUserId = reply.ApplicationUser.Id,
                ReplyUserName = reply.ApplicationUser.UserName
            });

    var model = new GetPostViewModel
            {
                Replies = listofReplies,
                Posts = BuildNewPost(post)
            };

    return View(model);
    // return View("GetPost", post);
}

private NewPostModel BuildNewPost(Post post)
{
    return new NewPostModel
            {
                PostId = post.Id,
                PostContent = post.Content,
                PostTitle = post.Title,
                DatePosted = post.Created.ToString(),
                DiscussionName = post.Discussion.Title,
                DiscussionId = post.Discussion.Id,
                UserId = post.ApplicationUser.Id,
                UserName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
            };
}
```

`GetReply` logic in service:

```
public PostReply GetReply(int id)
{
    return _context.Replies.Find(id);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `posts.Id` has a value?

Comment: Yes, when i step into the line of code: Post post = _postService.GetPost(id); - It shows that it does find the id of post. However: 'var replies = post.Replies' returns null.

Comment: could you share `GetReply` code in `replyService`

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've added it to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not including `replies` in your `GetPost()` methode,
So check if your code is like this:

```
 public Post GetPost(int id)
 {
     return _context.Posts.Include(p=>p.Replies).FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == id);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately still not working, I have tried that before. Thanks for your efforts though.